# Reading specific data from a line in a file - C++

Tags: c++

I have a .txt file divided like this:

```
(P1, 3): (E10, E20, E1, E3)
(P2, 2): (E10, E20, E2,  E5)
(P3, 2): (E10, E20)
```

I just want to save the **numbers** of each line in an array. EX: The first one would be [1,3,10,20,1,3]. How can I do that?

Comment: You probably want to read 1 line at a time into a `std::string` and parse the string in its own function.

Comment: Have you tried `operator >>` for `ifstream`? I don't remember if it gives an error if it encounters text or just skips it. But could work for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Iterate through the file reading it line by line using [ifstream](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/fstream/ifstream/ifstream/).

With the string read to a std::string, use [regex search](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/regex/regex_search/) to find the occurences of numbers in the newly read string.

The regex you want to use to extract all the numbers in a string is the following:

https://regex101.com/r/yWJp5p/3

An example of usage:

```
#include <regex>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

std::vector<std::string> fetchMatches(std::string str, const std::regex re) {
    std::vector<std::string> matches;
    std::smatch sm; // Use to get the matches as string

    while (regex_search(str, sm, re)) {
        matches.push_back(sm.str());
        str = sm.suffix();
    }

    return matches;
}

int main() {
    std::string example_input = "(P1, 3): (E10, E20, E1, E3)";

    std::regex re{"\\d+"};

    auto matches = fetchMatches(example_input, re);

    for (const auto& match : matches) {
        std::cout << match << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

There are multiple solutions. Explaining one of the solutions.

Using [isDigit](https://devdocs.io/c/string/byte/isdigit) and [strtol](https://devdocs.io/c/string/byte/strtol) functions of C.

```
char *str = "(P1, 3): (E10, E20, E1, E3)", *p = str;
while (*p) {
    if ( isdigit(*p)) {
        long val = strtol(p, &p, 10); 
        printf("%ld\n", val);
    } else {
        p++;
    }
}
```

Note: If the file has negative numbers, you will need to check for that.

Just add `((*p=='-'||*p=='+') && isdigit(*(p+1)))` in the if condition.